# Android, Qt, how to start a "hello world" service

Tags: android, c++, qt

I am trying to launch a simple service that just print "Service". However it is like my service is never executed (at least I don"t see any message from it in the application output).

Here is my main.cpp

```
#include <QAndroidService>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QGuiApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc == 1) {
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << "Application debug!!!";
    return app.exec();
  }

  else {
    QAndroidService app(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << "Service debug !!!";
    throw "lol";
    app.exec();
  }
}
```

Here my AndroidManifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<manifest package="org.qtproject.EasyMusicVideo" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="-- %%INSERT_VERSION_NAME%% --" android:versionCode="-- %%INSERT_VERSION_CODE%% --" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28"/>

    <!-- The following comment will be replaced upon deployment with default permissions based on the dependencies of the application.
         Remove the comment if you do not require these default permissions. -->
    <!-- %%INSERT_PERMISSIONS -->

    <!-- The following comment will be replaced upon deployment with default features based on the dependencies of the application.
         Remove the comment if you do not require these default features. -->
    <!-- %%INSERT_FEATURES -->

    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true"/>

    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtApplication" android:label="-- %%INSERT_APP_NAME%% --">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|mcc|mnc|density" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity" android:label="-- %%INSERT_APP_NAME%% --" android:screenOrientation="unspecified" android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Application arguments -->
            <!-- meta-data android:name="android.app.arguments" android:value="arg1 arg2 arg3"/ -->
            <!-- Application arguments -->

            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="-- %%INSERT_APP_LIB_NAME%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.qt_sources_resource_id" android:resource="@array/qt_sources"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.repository" android:value="default"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.qt_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/qt_libs"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_libs"/>
            <!-- Deploy Qt libs as part of package -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundle_local_qt_libs" android:value="-- %%BUNDLE_LOCAL_QT_LIBS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_in_lib_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_in_lib"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_in_assets_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_in_assets"/>
            <!-- Run with local libs -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.use_local_qt_libs" android:value="-- %%USE_LOCAL_QT_LIBS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.libs_prefix" android:value="/data/local/tmp/qt/"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.load_local_libs" android:value="-- %%INSERT_LOCAL_LIBS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.load_local_jars" android:value="-- %%INSERT_LOCAL_JARS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.static_init_classes" android:value="-- %%INSERT_INIT_CLASSES%% --"/>
            <!-- Used to specify custom system library path to run with local system libs -->
            <!-- <meta-data android:name="android.app.system_libs_prefix" android:value="/system/lib/"/> -->
            <!--  Messages maps -->
            <meta-data android:value="@string/ministro_not_found_msg" android:name="android.app.ministro_not_found_msg"/>
            <meta-data android:value="@string/ministro_needed_msg" android:name="android.app.ministro_needed_msg"/>
            <meta-data android:value="@string/fatal_error_msg" android:name="android.app.fatal_error_msg"/>
            <meta-data android:value="@string/unsupported_android_version" android:name="android.app.unsupported_android_version"/>
            <!--  Messages maps -->

            <!-- Splash screen -->
            <!-- Orientation-specific (portrait/landscape) data is checked first. If not available for current orientation,
                 then android.app.splash_screen_drawable. For best results, use together with splash_screen_sticky and
                 use hideSplashScreen() with a fade-out animation from Qt Android Extras to hide the splash screen when you
                 are done populating your window with content. -->
            <!-- meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_drawable_portrait" android:resource="@drawable/logo_portrait" / -->
            <!-- meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_drawable_landscape" android:resource="@drawable/logo_landscape" / -->
            <!-- meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_drawable" android:resource="@drawable/logo"/ -->
            <!-- meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_sticky" android:value="true"/ -->
            <!-- Splash screen -->

            <!-- Background running -->
            <!-- Warning: changing this value to true may cause unexpected crashes if the
                          application still try to draw after
                          "applicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationSuspended)"
                          signal is sent! -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.background_running" android:value="false"/>
            <!-- Background running -->

            <!-- auto screen scale factor -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.auto_screen_scale_factor" android:value="false"/>
            <!-- auto screen scale factor -->

            <!-- extract android style -->
            <!-- available android:values :
                * default - In most cases this will be the same as "full", but it can also be something else if needed, e.g., for compatibility reasons
                * full - useful QWidget & Quick Controls 1 apps
                * minimal - useful for Quick Controls 2 apps, it is much faster than "full"
                * none - useful for apps that don't use any of the above Qt modules
                -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.extract_android_style" android:value="minimal"/>
            <!-- extract android style -->
        </activity>

        <service android:process=":qt" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtService">
        <!-- android:process=":qt" is needed to force the service to run on a separate process than the Activity -->
            <!-- Application arguments -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.arguments" android:value="-service"/>
            <!-- Application arguments -->

            <!-- Application to launch -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="-- %%INSERT_APP_LIB_NAME%% --"/>
            <!-- Application to launch -->

            <!-- Ministro -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.qt_sources_resource_id" android:resource="@array/qt_sources"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.repository" android:value="default"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.qt_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/qt_libs"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_libs"/>
            <!-- Ministro -->

            <!-- Deploy Qt libs as part of package -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundle_local_qt_libs" android:value="-- %%BUNDLE_LOCAL_QT_LIBS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_in_lib_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_in_lib"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_in_assets_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_in_assets"/>
            <!-- Deploy Qt libs as part of package -->

            <!-- Run with local libs -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.use_local_qt_libs" android:value="-- %%USE_LOCAL_QT_LIBS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.libs_prefix" android:value="/data/local/tmp/qt/"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.load_local_libs" android:value="-- %%INSERT_LOCAL_LIBS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.load_local_jars" android:value="-- %%INSERT_LOCAL_JARS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.static_init_classes" android:value="-- %%INSERT_INIT_CLASSES%% --"/>
            <!-- Run with local libs -->

            <!--  Messages maps -->
            <meta-data android:value="@string/ministro_not_found_msg" android:name="android.app.ministro_not_found_msg"/>
            <meta-data android:value="@string/ministro_needed_msg" android:name="android.app.ministro_needed_msg"/>
            <meta-data android:value="@string/fatal_error_msg" android:name="android.app.fatal_error_msg"/>
            <!--  Messages maps -->


            <!-- Background running -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.background_running" android:value="true"/>
            <!-- Background running -->
        </service>
    </application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
</manifest>
```

And here is what I get from the Application Output :

```
I .EasyMusicVide: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
I .EasyMusicVide: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I Perf    : Connecting to perf service.
V Font    : Change font:2
W /system/bin/tc-wrapper-1.0: type=1400 audit(0.0:1097439): avc: denied { read } for comm=45474C20496E6974 name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=18103 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c82,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
E libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.profiler"
W /system/bin/tc-wrapper-1.0: type=1400 audit(0.0:1097440): avc: denied { read } for comm=45474C20496E6974 name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=18103 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c82,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
E libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.prerotation.disable"
W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
E libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.perf.gestureflingboost.enable"
V FlingOptimizerScroller: FlingOptimizerOverScroller Init
W .EasyMusicVideo: type=1400 audit(0.0:1097441): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=18103 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c82,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
D OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
I QtCore  : Start
W linker  : Warning: "/data/app/org.qtproject.EasyMusicVideo-FUikYpny7lK0oXieloTmdQ==/lib/arm/libQt5AndroidExtras.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80 (ignoring unsupported flags)
W linker  : Warning: "/data/app/org.qtproject.EasyMusicVideo-FUikYpny7lK0oXieloTmdQ==/lib/arm/libQt5Gui.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80 (ignoring unsupported flags)
W linker  : Warning: "/data/app/org.qtproject.EasyMusicVideo-FUikYpny7lK0oXieloTmdQ==/lib/arm/libQt5Network.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80 (ignoring unsupported flags)
W linker  : Warning: "/data/app/org.qtproject.EasyMusicVideo-FUikYpny7lK0oXieloTmdQ==/lib/arm/libQt5Multimedia.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80 (ignoring unsupported flags)
W linker  : Warning: "/data/app/org.qtproject.EasyMusicVideo-FUikYpny7lK0oXieloTmdQ==/lib/arm/libQt5Widgets.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80 (ignoring unsupported flags)
W linker  : Warning: "/data/app/org.qtproject.EasyMusicVideo-FUikYpny7lK0oXieloTmdQ==/lib/arm/libQt5OpenGL.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80 (ignoring unsupported flags)
W linker  : Warning: "/data/app/org.qtproject.EasyMusicVideo-FUikYpny7lK0oXieloTmdQ==/lib/arm/libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80 (ignoring unsupported flags)
W linker  : Warning: "/data/app/org.qtproject.EasyMusicVideo-FUikYpny7lK0oXieloTmdQ==/lib/arm/libQt5Qml.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80 (ignoring unsupported flags)
W linker  : Warning: "/data/app/org.qtproject.EasyMusicVideo-FUikYpny7lK0oXieloTmdQ==/lib/arm/libQt5Quick.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80 (ignoring unsupported flags)
W linker  : Warning: "/data/app/org.qtproject.EasyMusicVideo-FUikYpny7lK0oXieloTmdQ==/lib/arm/libQt5MultimediaQuick.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80 (ignoring unsupported flags)
W linker  : Warning: "/data/app/org.qtproject.EasyMusicVideo-FUikYpny7lK0oXieloTmdQ==/lib/arm/libQt5QuickParticles.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80 (ignoring unsupported flags)
W linker  : Warning: "/data/app/org.qtproject.EasyMusicVideo-FUikYpny7lK0oXieloTmdQ==/lib/arm/libQt5QuickTemplates2.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80 (ignoring unsupported flags)
W linker  : Warning: "/data/app/org.qtproject.EasyMusicVideo-FUikYpny7lK0oXieloTmdQ==/lib/arm/libQt5QuickControls2.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80 (ignoring unsupported flags)
W linker  : Warning: "/data/app/org.qtproject.EasyMusicVideo-FUikYpny7lK0oXieloTmdQ==/lib/arm/libQt5RemoteObjects.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80 (ignoring unsupported flags)
W linker  : Warning: "/data/data/org.qtproject.EasyMusicVideo/qt-reserved-files/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80 (ignoring unsupported flags)
I Qt      : qt started
W linker  : Warning: "/data/data/org.qtproject.EasyMusicVideo/qt-reserved-files/plugins/bearer/libqandroidbearer.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80 (ignoring unsupported flags)
W linker  : Warning: "/data/data/org.qtproject.EasyMusicVideo/qt-reserved-files/plugins/mediaservice/libqtmedia_android.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80 (ignoring unsupported flags)
I Qt JAVA : Can't find '/data/data/org.qtproject.EasyMusicVideo/qt-reserved-files/lib/libQt5MultimediaQuick.so'
I Qt JAVA : Can't find '/data/data/org.qtproject.EasyMusicVideo/qt-reserved-files/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so'
W .EasyMusicVide: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->ViewDrawableStates:[I (light greylist, reflection)
W .EasyMusicVide: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_background:I (light greylist, reflection)
.........
W .EasyMusicVide: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_scrollbarFadeDuration:I (light greylist, reflection)
W .EasyMusicVide: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade:I (light greylist, reflection)
W .EasyMusicVide: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->LinearLayout_divider:I (light greylist, reflection)
W .EasyMusicVide: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->LinearLayout_showDividers:I (light greylist, reflection)
W .EasyMusicVide: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->LinearLayout_dividerPadding:I (light greylist, reflection)
E linker  : normalize_path - invalid input: "C", the input path should be absolute
W linker  : Warning: unable to normalize "C" (ignoring)
E linker  : normalize_path - invalid input: "C", the input path should be absolute
W linker  : Warning: unable to normalize "C" (ignoring)
E libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.perf.gestureflingboost.enable"
W .EasyMusicVideo: type=1400 audit(0.0:1097442): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=18103 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c82,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
V ViewRootImpl: The specified message queue synchronization  barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed
D DecorView: onWindowFocusChangedFromViewRoot hasFocus: true, DecorView@7b61acd[QtActivity]
I Adreno  : QUALCOMM build                   : f909f5a, Ida6448821d
I Adreno  : Build Date                       : 11/12/18
I Adreno  : OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.25.03.00
I Adreno  : Local Branch                     :
I Adreno  : Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.7.3.R1.08.00.00.423.039
I Adreno  : Remote Branch                    : NONE
I Adreno  : Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
I Adreno  : Build Config                     : S P 6.0.3 AArch32
E libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.prerotation.disable"
E libc    : Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.graphics.memory"
E libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.prerotation.disable"
W RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:1097443): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=18103 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c82,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
E libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.prerotation.disable"
I Adreno  : PFP: 0x016ee170, ME: 0x00000000
E libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.prerotation.disable"
V ViewRootImpl: The specified message queue synchronization  barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed
I ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 1
I ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
E libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.changepixelformat"
E libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
D         : Successfully load libgui-plugin.so, this=0xec377068
D libEasyMusicVideo.so: Application debug!!!
E libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
```

It seems the service never start. Is it normal? Have I forget something?

Comment: https://www.kdab.com/qt-android-create-android-service-using-qt/

Comment: Yes the problem was solved, I thought we did not need to call java code since I was using QAndroidService.
Thanks. But I was wrong